# how to change null value to 0 and trivial/sum it using PHP for Oracle

Tags: php, oracle

How do I change null value to 0 and trivial(sum) it using PHP function for Oracle? Below is my current code

```
   $conn = ......;
   $strSQL = .....;
   $objParse = oci_parse ($conn, $strSQL);
   oci_execute ($objParse);
   $total_tonnage = 0;
   while($objResult = oci_fetch_array($objParse,OCI_BOTH))
   {
    $total_tonnage += $objResult["TON"];
   }
   echo $total_tonnage;
```

When I run above code, i recieved

> SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for

and

> Notice: Undefined index: TON

For your information, when there's no null value. Its running fine. That error occurred when got null/empty value.

Comment: a- can't you use [NVL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions105.htm) in the query? b- can't you sum the values in the query?

Comment: And why not just use oracle's `sum`?

Comment: For your information, the query is about 300++ lines and I'm not really good playing with the query. So I would prefer to use PHP function.

Answer (score 0):

```
   while($objResult = oci_fetch_array($objParse,OCI_BOTH))
   {
    $total_tonnage += array_key_exists('TON', $objResult) ? $objResult["TON"] : 0;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in the DB as well-

Usually when you need to query nulls as values you can use the [NVL function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions105.htm), IE:

```
SELECT nvl(TON, 0) , -- other columns here
FROM your_table
-- rest of the 300++ lines
```

If you only need to sum the value and you don't want to change the 300++ query you can do something like this:

```
SELECT sum(TON)
FROM (<your 300++ query>)
```

If you need the sum and the other columns (you don't want to "group by") then you can do:

```
SELECT t.*, sum(t.TON) over()
FROM (<your 300++ query>) t
```